# Is the CodeProject Quick Answers site a clone, affiliated or a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, clone

Came across [CodeProject Quick Answers](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Answers/List.aspx) today.

From the looks of things, it offers a similar experience to that of the Stack Exchange sites.

Is it in any way affiliated? Is it a Stack Exchange site? Or is it some kind of clone?

What's your take on their endeavour if it's neither an affiliate or Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Couldn't you have asked this on http://Meta.StackExchange.com/ instead if that's your main base point?

Comment: Ow, they must be feeling the competition. I must admit that as much as I don't mind putting sex changers out of business, code project is another proposition entirely. Maybe they should work out a deal (close - belongs on code project ;)

Comment: Stackoverflow could branch out to a full article sister site ;)

Comment: Went there, clicked on a random question, saw that the top answer was copied (with attribution) from a Stack Overflow question, went "meh".

Comment: Do we need a question for every clone/affiliate/stack exchange site?

Comment: What was that rollback over a rollback about?

Comment: Just for the badge, restored it as you rewrote it, no harm done.

Comment: Oh the Cleanup badge. What other badges are you looking for?

Comment: ;)) yes, it was the cleanup indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, neither. Similar features were under discussion long before the release of SO, as the CP forums had become clogged with off-topic, poorly-asked questions.

Unfortunately, it doesn't offer any equivalent to the close and delete features of SO, so there's no good way to quickly shut down duplicate questions or questions that are missing necessary information. CP would do well to look to SO for improvements.

Those that wish to further neuter SO's "close" functionality would do well to examine CP's Quick Answers...

Answer (score 11):

**It's a clone - not a StackExchange nor affiliated.**

Personally, I find the layout hard to read and unappealing.

There doesn't seem to be many rules for it either - many of the answers seem to treat the place as if it's a message board.

Answer (score 2):

It does have a certain visual similarity, and I wouldn't be surprised if it was SO inspired, but it seems to be just a cheap imitation.

SO is already changing the internet for programmers ...

Answer (score 1):

"The Stack" is all the rage today in the tech world. Everybody wants in. :)

Comment: This would better be a comment.

Comment: @neolisk - IIRC comments weren't an option in 2009... or at least the social conventions were a little different.

Comment: It's never too late to catch up with today's standards. :)